# specific time in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clean my data set in excel. Currently, my code deletes data before 7 am and after 10 pm. how do I make it 7:30 am?

current code:

```
If Hour(.Cells(Cell, 2)) < 7 Or Hour(.Cells(Cell, 2)) > 22
```

I want to make the 7 to 7:30. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
if TimeValue(.Cells(Cell, 2)) > #7:30:00 AM# Or TimeVa...
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what is the format of the data in your `Cells(Cell, 2)`, if it is as in the `Now`function you could do this:

```
'Example with `Now`
If CInt(Hour(.Cells(Cell, 2)) & Minute(.Cells(Cell, 2))) < 730 Or _
    Hour(.Cells(Cell, 2)) > 22 Then
```

Answer (score 3):

Hour() will always return and integer. Try converting the time to a string:  `Format(Range("H1"), "hhnn")` for the comparison.